# MS Access Database VBA back-end check makes project stop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to lookup if back-end DB is located correctly
after I run My code, if it returned with an error, everything is fine, but when it comes back without an error hence it makes the whole application stop.
following is my VBA code:

```
Function CheckLinkedDb()
cDBPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim Relink_Tables
Dim rsCheckLink As Recordset
Relink_Tables = False
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
      If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
        ''Linked table - test link is current
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            On Error Resume Next 'Do not stop script on error
            Set rsCheckLink = db.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name) ' OPEN TABLE
            DoCmd.Echo False, "Checking link for table " & tdf.Name
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            If Err Then ' COULD NOT OPEN TABLE
                Relink_Tables = True
                'GoTo Relink_Tables ' RECONNECT TO APPROPIATE DATABASE
            Else
                rsCheckLink.Close ' CLOSE TABLE THAT DID OPEN
                Set rsCheckLink = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next

If Relink_Tables = True Then
    goto RelinkT....
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have `DoCmd.Echo True` somewhere later in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong, also not sure what "it makes the whole application stop" means - an endless loop?

You should remove the `DoCmd.SetWarnings False / True` statements, they are not needed.

And it is a good habit when using `On Error Resume Next` to check for error immediately after the possible error line. And: always reset it as soon as possible, don't run multiple code lines without error handling.

So your code should be:

```
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
     If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
        ''Linked table - test link is current
            DoCmd.Echo False, "Checking link for table " & tdf.Name
            On Error Resume Next 'Do not stop script on error
            Set rsCheckLink = db.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name) ' OPEN TABLE
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then ' COULD NOT OPEN TABLE
                On Error Goto 0
                Relink_Tables = True
                'GoTo Relink_Tables ' RECONNECT TO APPROPIATE DATABASE
            Else
                On Error Goto 0
                rsCheckLink.Close ' CLOSE TABLE THAT DID OPEN
                Set rsCheckLink = Nothing
            End If
    End If
Next
```

If the problem is still there, use: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine,  the only problem is that after the DB check I have a command of `DoCmd.OpenForm "MyMainForm"` which is ignored, (if the file is opened by double-clicking) only if I close the DB from the Access's main menu and then re-open it from the 'recent files list' then it will work properly why is that???